# Sinatra-synchrony detect_rack_handler not found

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm attempting to run Sinatra with the sinatra-synchrony mod. backed up by Thin.

Code:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/synchrony'
```

Causes an immediate error:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.2.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1290:in `detect_rack_handler': Server handler (thin,mongrel,webrick) not found. (RuntimeError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.2.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1230:in `run!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.2.6/lib/sinatra/main.rb:25:in `block in <module:Sinatra>
```

**My setup**

- ruby 1.9.2p0
- thin 1.2.11
- sinatra: 1.2.6
- sinatra-synchrony: 0.2.0

Comment: I might also add that I'm running the program in Classic mode, just `ruby app.rb` and let Sinatra set everything up itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have pushed 0.2.1, which resolves this issue. Basically there's a constant that wasn't being defined correctly in the async-rack code. Since async-rack was primarily just being used to fix a dumb logging issue, I've removed it for now. Perhaps in the future I will fix the logging by extracting the part of async-rack that actually fixes this. For now I'm going to just pull the code out. So try 0.2.1 and see if that resolves it.

Comment: Just tried it and works perfectly, except for no logging as you mentioned. Thanks!